# Override iPhone copy menu captions on a long-press?

Tags: iphone, menu, copy, paste, cut

Is it possible to override the captions in the "Copy" menu when the iphone user long-presses on some text? Essentially, I'd like to change the text to something like "Create a Note" instead of "Copy". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom menus via UIMenuController's menuItems property, something like:

```
UIMenuItem* item1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"One" action:@selector(DoThingOne:)];
UIMenuItem* item2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Two" action:@selector(DoThingTwo:)];
[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item1, item2, nil] autorelease];
[item1 release];
[item2 release];
```

However, this is only in iPhone OS 3.2, which would make it iPad only at this point.  There's an example [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Text/Text.html) (scroll down to "Custom Edit Menu Items").

As for altering the existing items, I do not believe that is possible currently.