# Detecting text hilight in a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView to display text on iPad. So far so good. Is there a way to detect when the user hilights text on a page, and override the default menu action so I can have the text do other things?

-Chris

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find something usefull here: [Override iPhone copy menu captions on a long-press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760897/override-iphone-copy-menu-captions-on-a-long-press)